# Formula or VBA for cell formatting using value based on a cell but formatting from an other cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, conditional-formatting, cells

I have a fixed set of values, (0%,20%,40%,60%,80% and 100%) in column E.

If I fill a cell in column E with any of the above values, the cell G should pick formatting from another cell.

For example,

```
if I fill 0 in E3, the cell G3 should pick formatting from H3
if I fill 20 in E3, the cell G3 should pick formatting from H3
if I fill 40 in E3, the cell G3 should pick formatting from I3
if I fill 60 in E3, the cell G3 should pick formatting from J3
if I fill 80 in E3, the cell G3 should pick formatting from K3
if I fill 100 in E3, the cell G3 should pick formatting from L3
```

I know it can be done in a series of conditional formatting but it is a bit difficult for to do it. Also, wanted to see if there is a simple answer?

Comment: Without conditional formatting the only option is VBA, but if you don't know it, then conditional formatting is definitely easier.

Comment: Conditional formatting is your answer here. Make sure your rules step properly and terminate on true.

Comment: @Raystafarian - With conditional formatting, how would you tell it to look at the various cells for the format type? Or are you suggesting to just set upp five different rules (one for H3, I3, J3, K3, L3), instead of having it "look" to another cell for format type?

Comment: I'd have multiple rules, I'm pretty sure conditional formatting, like functions, can't read format. @bruce

Answer (score 0):

Just as illustration, below is a simple VBA macro that does the formatting. It's up to you to decide if it's simple. Something similar could be put into the Worksheet_Change event sub.

This is a little more flexible than conditional formatting, because you can have different formats on each of row of the column your choosing the format from. (e.g. see column H in the screen cap's).

Here is a screen capture of the worksheet before running the macro ...

[image]

And here is a screen capture after running the macro ...

[image]

And here is the VBA code ...

```
Sub FormatTransfer()
Dim mySht As Worksheet
Dim myInRng As Range, myOutRng As Range, myFmtRng As Range
Dim myCell As Range

Set mySht = Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set myInRng = mySht.Range("E1", mySht.Range("E" & mySht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set myOutRng = myInRng.Offset(0, 2)
Set myFmtRng = mySht.Range(myInRng.Offset(0, 3), myInRng.Offset(0, 7))

For Each myCell In myInRng
    If myCell.Value < 20# Then
        myFmtRng(myCell.Row, 1).Copy
        myOutRng(myCell.Row, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End If
    If myCell.Value >= 20# And myCell.Value < 40# Then
        myFmtRng(myCell.Row, 1).Copy
        myOutRng(myCell.Row, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End If
    If myCell.Value >= 40# And myCell.Value < 60# Then
        myFmtRng(myCell.Row, 2).Copy
        myOutRng(myCell.Row, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End If
    If myCell.Value >= 60# And myCell.Value < 80# Then
        myFmtRng(myCell.Row, 3).Copy
        myOutRng(myCell.Row, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End If
    If myCell.Value >= 80# And myCell.Value <= 100# Then
         myFmtRng(myCell.Row, 4).Copy
         myOutRng(myCell.Row, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
   End If
Next myCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I did tried using multiple conditional formatting rules and it did work. How ever, to determine the number of red formatted cells in a column is bit tricky. As the rules change the colors of the cell changes. If cell format changes from red to green the color doesn't change dynamically. If applied to a static cell the formula =GET.CELL(63,INDIRECT("rc",FALSE)) seems to work. Any help to determine the dynamically changing colour of the cell ?Thanks